# Remove SQL Server default date of 1/1/1900

Tags: vb.net

The user can select a date with the following code and the date is display in a TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dateTB" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ib" ImageUrl="/calendar.png" ImageAlign="Bottom" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="Cal1" PopupButtonID="ib" runat="server" TargetControlID="dateTB" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

After that, I am storing that date in a SQL Server database.

Problem: when the user doesn't enter a date, SQL Server is storing 1/1/1900 as default.

What can I do so if the user leaves an empty date field then SQL Server doesn't store 1/1/1900?

What I have tried: what if I check to see is dateTB is empty. If it's empty then do something and then insert in database.

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTB.Text)) Then
    ' do something with dateTB??
End If
```

What I want to happen: if it's the default date (1/1/1900) then I want to store null, not 1/1/1900.

Comment: what do you want to happen?

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: It might be easier for us to help if you show the code which you use to insert data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your database column supports NULL.
2. Make sure your VB code is passing DBNull for the value you are setting.

Since you don't have a full example, I'm guessing that the field in VB code you are using to store the date value is not nullable, so it is getting set to the default value. You can fix this by using nullable types. Do not use magic values; 1/1/1900 is a legitimate date.